# Is it possible? Arcane Archer at lvl 5?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class

So here is my dilemma. I'm starting a Pathfinder campaign and a new Player, his first time making a character and playing Pathfinder, has read up on the Arcane Archer Prestige Class, and I'm trying to find a way to make it for him at lvl 5. I'm starting all my players at lvl 5 and allowing multi-class(3 in one class, 2 in another at the very least, but I'm flexible). Is there a way that we could bring the prestige class in at lvl 5? I'm able to get the feats and casting requirements no problem, the issue I'm running into is the BAB of +6. I have a feeling that it will not be possible, but I want a 2nd opinion. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What aspects of the arcane archer are important here? What are you trying to achieve with this build?

Comment: Honestly, that is a very good question that I haven't asked him yet. I would think that it's the idea of combining spells with your archery attacks, but that's just my observation from his attitude towards it.

Comment: While this question is answerable as-is, I'd recommend reformulating it in light of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) Describe your problem instead of the solution you thought of. Discuss with the player what he wants to get out of the character. We also need to know what kind of eyebrow-raising shenanigans you're willing to tolerate with regards to optimisation.

Comment: Yeah, I will definitely ask him what aspects of this class are appealing to him. Because he's a new player I want to be able to have him play a character he is genuinely interested and invested in. I'm willing to work this however I can, shenanigans are always fun...

Comment: Then in the interests of getting you the best possible answer, I'm going to close this pending edit for character requirements. Take a look at our [optimisation guidelines](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1641/760) for what we look for here, since that will help you elicit requirements from your player.

Comment: Isn't this question simply asking if it's 'alright' to lower the requirements of the prestige class?  That's perfectly fine.  It's a weaker class than straight wizard, and changing stuff about the mechanics of the game is called 'homebrewing' and happens all the time everywhere.

Comment: @JackLesnie I didn't get that impression of its meaning at all, which means it's unclear to at least one of us.

Comment: I think the questions I'd like clarified on this answer are: 1) Is the question “What tricks can be abused to do this?” or is the question “Is it OK to houserule and let him do this?” 2) What about arcane archer interests the player? and 3) What, exactly, is the houseruling about multiclassing that’s going on? (DMs don’t typically “allow” multiclassing, or particular multiclass arrangements; it’s just a default option available to players)